# How to get closest previous id from array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object,I want to get the closest previous id from nearest object.I can able to get closest next id,its working fine but for previous is not working.Its taking direct first id of object.Here is the code below.Can anyone please help me on it.

### JAVASCRIPT

```js
const array = [{id:4}, {id:10}, {id:15}];

const findClosesPrevtId = (x) => ( array.find( ({id}) => x <= id ) || {} ).id;
const findClosestNextId = (x) => ( array.find( ({id}) => x >= id ) || {} ).id;

console.log(findClosesPrevtId(5));
console.log(findClosestNextId(11));
```

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: _"able to get closest next id"_ - That doesn't work either: `4` should be `15`

Answer (score 2):

Cause `x <= i` will be fullfilled for the first element if you use `find` to search from left to right. Use `findLast` to search from right to left.

Unfortunately I just found out that there is actually not a `findLast` yet (there is `reduceRight`, `lastIndexOf` ... :/), so you have to write it yourself:

```
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "findLast", {
    value(cb, context) {
       for(let i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
         if(cb.call(context, this[i], i, this))
            return this[i];
   }
 });

const findClosesPrevtId = (x) => ( array.findLast( ({id}) => x <= id ) || {} ).id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your code and it should work now.
Have a look.

```js
    const array = [{id:3}, {id:4}, {id:10}, {id:15}];
    // you should order the list by id before you try to search, this incase you have not orginized list.
    // filter the list first and get the prev id to 5 
    // you should get 3 and 4 then 
    // slice(-1) to get the last element of the array which should be 4
    const findClosesPrevtId = (x) =>
    (array.filter(({id}) => id <= x ).slice(-1)[0] || {}).id;
    const findClosestNextId = (x) => 
    (array.filter(({id}) => id >= x )[0] || {}).id;

    console.log("Prev to 5:"+ findClosesPrevtId(5));
    console.log("Next to 11:" +findClosestNextId(11));
```

Comment: Ok i added some explnation. Tell me otherwise what is it you dont understand.

Comment: Can you please use find instead of slice ,I am not getting slice(-1)[0],what is for.when I am using this in angular 4 its not changing the value of id

Comment: `find` will return the first value which is 3 as an example above. `filter` will return a list eg 3 and 4 then `slice` will return the last value of the list which is 4. `slice()` is javascript so it should work angular or react without problem. Have a look at @Jonas Wilms answer. he build a function called findlast, which do exactly as slice whith the exception of searching.

Comment: I edited the code. You dont need to use slice for the `findClosestNextId` but slice or similar have to be used in `findClosesPrevtId`

Answer (score 0):

You could store the precious/next element and stop the iteration if `id` is greater than the wanted id.

```js
const
    closestPrevious = id => {
        var last = {};
        array.some(o => o.id > id || (last = o, false))
        return last.id;
    },
    closestNext = id => {
        var next = array[0];
        array.some((o, i, { [i + 1]: n = {} }) => o.id > id || (next = n, false))
        return next.id;
    },
    array = [{ id: 4 }, { id: 10 }, { id: 15 }];

console.log(closestNext(5));      // 10
console.log(closestNext(11));     // 15

console.log(closestPrevious(5));  //  4
console.log(closestPrevious(11)); // 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to reverse the array and switch the comparison from `>=` to `<=`:

```js
const findClosestNextId  = (x, arr) => 
  (arr.find ( ({id}) => id >= x) || {} ) .id

const findClosestPrevId  = (x, arr) => 
  (arr .slice(0) .reverse() .find ( ({id}) => id <= x) || {}) .id

const array = [{ id: 4 }, { id: 10 }, { id: 15 }];

console .log (
  findClosestNextId (5,  array), //=> 10
  findClosestNextId (11, array), //=> 15
  findClosestNextId (42, array), //=> undefined

  findClosestPrevId (5,  array), //=> 4
  findClosestPrevId (11, array), //=> 10
  findClosestPrevId (2,  array), //=> undefined
)
```

The `slice` call is there to prevent this from modifying the original array.  This will return `undefined` if there is no element found.